# FinancialForce component ? What are they ? how do they work?

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

I recently came across a custom financial force component

`<ffirule:IntegrationRule engine="{!engine}"/>`

which is very similar to custom visualforce components but don't they usually start with

`<c:customComponentName/>`

Are these custom components ? How are they created ? Can someone explain me the usage ?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are package components with a namespace prefix. When you enable a developer/isv org to create packages you should pick a namespace. This namespace will be specific to all your custom components (but also custom fields etc) and they will be known as such in any org that deploys your package.

[image: package]

You still define and build components the way you're used to:
[image: component]

In a visualforce pages you can no longer use the `c:` notaction but have to use your namespace prefix:
[image: visualforce page]

So, these components work just the same way as the ones you're building yourself, but they are designed to also work in other orgs where they should have a separated name from anything else already there.